# How can i change default Onesignal font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, onesignal

Recently i installed OneSignal plugin for Wordpress. everything is ok but i want to change default font-family and use my website font. the problem is that OneSignal uses external CSS:

[External CSS from onesignal server](https://onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKStyles.css)

I Can`t change it. How can i use another font?
I tried:

```
$(.onesignal-bell-launcher-message).css("font-family":"");
```

but doesnt work.

Comment: Can't you just override the relevant font-family classes of oneSignal with your own local css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `!important`

```
.onesignal-bell-launcher-message {
  font-family: arial !important;
}
```

Comment: It works. didn`n know local css priority is more than external.

Comment: Used `!important` to override external css.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped so other people can know this one is solved :)

Comment: Thank You Manish.